# LibraryLink: Asynchronous Examples

Tags: undocumented, librarylink, asynchronous-processing

Inside the directory structure of `LibraryLink` there are several example files. Basically, they are divided in two types:

- **Synchronous:** demo.c, demo_error.c, demo_eval.c, demo_mathlink.c, demo_numerical.c, demo_shared.c, demo_string.c
- **Asynchronous:** async-examples-libmain.c, async-tasks-oneshot.c, async-tasks-repeating.c, async-tasks-timing.c, async-tasks-without-thread.c

The `synchronous` examples are well documented and relatively easy to use. However, the `asynchronous` are undocumented (as far as I know) and more difficult to use. So far, after some guesswork, the best I could figure it out is the following:

**File Description**

- *async-examples-libmain.c:* Initialization instructions (nothing to be executed within Mathematica).
- *async-tasks-oneshot.c:* Example of how to execute a task one single time and then close it.
- *async-tasks-repeating.c:* Example of how to execute a task continuously. This can be seen at the function `IntBackgroundTask` which has a `while loop` to keep the task alive.
- *async-tasks-timing.c:* Example of how to execute a task with time constraint. This can be seen at the function `IntBackgroundTask` which has a `for loop` limited by an iterator.
- *async-tasks-without-thread.c:* ????

**File Structure**
The main function of each one of the files is `start_*_background_task` and they are all very similar:

- The arguments are the same as of the synchronous ones (ie: always 3 arguments).
- The lines between `mint asyncObjID;` and `asyncObjID = ioLibrary->createAsynchronousTaskWithThread(IntBackgroundTask, threadArg);` sets and creates the asynchronous task.
- `MArgument_setInteger` returns a value to Mathematica, currently is returning only the value of `asyncObjID`. However, more calculations could be copy & paste before this line.

---

**1st Issue**
My guesswork is correct? Did I miss something?

**2nd Issue**
What the example file `async-tasks-without-thread.c` do?

**3rd Issue**
I'm trying to create a library for each one of the aforementioned files but some of them are not working. For example, when I execute the following:

```
<< CCompilerDriver`
demoFile = First@FileNames["async-tasks-oneshot.c", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity];
lib = CreateLibrary[{demoFile}, "mylib"];
```

I receive the following error message:

```
CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\Links\LibraryLink\LibraryResources\Source\async-tasks-oneshot.c(5) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'async-examples.h': No such file or directory >>
```

The same happens with "async-tasks-repeating.c" and "async-tasks-without-thread.c".

What is going on? How to fix it?

**4th Issue**
If I just load the library (instead of creating it), I also get some behaviours not understood yet. For example:

```
fun = LibraryFunctionLoad["async-tasks-oneshot", "start_int_background_task", {Integer, Integer}, Integer];
fun[0, 0]

Out[2]:=1
```

I was expecting the output to be `asyncObjID` due the line `MArgument_setInteger(Res, asyncObjID)`. Why this is not the case?

**5th Issue**
Moreover, after calling this `fun[0,0]`, I can not evaluate anything else. For example:

```
1+1
```

It stays in the evaluation queue forever, but never returns an answer.
Why this is happening? How to properly call the asynchronous function `fun`?

---

ps: Anticipating some comments, I'm trying to use this asynchronous feature in order to solve an issue with [Low Level Networking Programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103595/low-level-networking-programming).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31433/12 Once I asked support about the `DataStore` type and they said " The DataStore type is part of an as-yet-undocumented C interface to pass event data from an asynchronous task. URLFetch uses this, as an example. But it only works asynchronously. And so far it is for internal use only."  They also pointed to the example programs you reference.

Comment: @Szabolcs _[...] so far it is for internal use only._ Unfortunately this is a very bad news, I was counting on this features to move ahead. But ok, I respect the NDA.

Comment: @halirutan Do you agree with the comments above? Or do you consider that is still possible to use such asynchronous features? as we have talked before on [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34000/discussion-between-halirutan-and-mark-messa)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I didn't mention anything about NDAs.  All I said was that I asked support about a certain thing related to these examples.  I did not ask questions as specific as yours.  They responded that these features are not publicly documented, but suggested that I can look at the provided example source code and learn from it.  This was back in 2013.  You can certainly try to figure out how to use these features, and asking about them here on StackExchange was a good idea.

Comment: @Szabolcs _I didn't mention anything about NDAs_ There is a comment in your [old question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31433/what-are-these-new-librarylink-functions-and-datatypes-for) mentioning that maybe nobody could answer it because of NDAs. I though that such NDAs might still be a constraint today.

Comment: @Szabolcs _[...] asking about them here on StackExchange was a good idea._ Ok, let's see if somebody knows the answer. Unfortunately, without further support, I don't know what else I could do to make them work.

Answer (score 6):

In Mathematica version 11.0 everything you need to know can be found in

```
SystemFiles/Links/LibraryLink/Examples.m
```

There, you find how you can call such a library function from within Mathematica. For example

```
CreateTimeDelayBackgroundTask[delayMillis_Integer, eventData_Integer, eventHandler_] := 
        Internal`CreateAsynchronousTask[startBackgroundTaskReturningInt, 
                {delayMillis, eventData}, eventHandler]
```

I don't comment on your first two issues, but for the answers for the rest are:

3. Seems to be no issue anymore. To solve it on an older version, just edit the example and remove the missing `#include`. I guess the came from some template code and did contain nothing or only forward declarations.
4. The returned `1` is indeed the `asyncObjID`. I tested it and after starting several task the value is incremented.
5. Well, if you call `f[0,0]` you say that you want a delay of 0 milliseconds. This might have been a problem. As can be seen in the example above, you need to use `` Internal`CreateAsynchronousTask `` and provide the loaded library function.

Finally, if you want a working example except for the ones the are provided by Mathematica, you can look at my answer that shows how to implement an [asynchronous file watcher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138433/187).