# LibraryLink: What are DataStore and WolframIOLibrary?

Tags: librarylink, asynchronous-processing

Version 9 introduced `DataStore` and `WolframIOLibrary_Functions` in `WolframLibrary.h`.  They don't seem to be documented.

There are some examples using these in

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "LibraryLink", "LibraryResources", "Source"}]
```

The examples are in the files named as `async-*`.

What is this functionality for? It would be nice to have a short introduction or tutorial on using these.

---

Possibly related:

- [LibraryLink: What can we do with MInputStream and MOutputStream?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31433/12)

Comment: This can probably be figured out based on the examples.  I will not be able to do this right away, but I wanted to put the question out there in case anyone else is interested.  Otherwise I will give it a try in a few weeks.  If someone posts a nice answer, I will award a 500 bounty.  I will not set the bounty it now to avoid time pressure.

Comment: Does this post about midway down answer your question? https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2133603

Comment: Here's a [good example](https://wolframresearch.github.io/LibraryLinkUtilities/modules/functions.html#user-defined-types) to help understand it