# WSTP Communicate to an external Mathematica Window

Tags: front-end, mathlink-or-wstp

I am using WSTP to connect to Mathematica and get my computation tasks performed via WSTP Link. This connection is initiated with `WSOpenArgcArgv`. It looks like I am using a command line based Mathematica frontend while invoking Mathematica commands. Can I execute an expression to another Mathematica GUI Window, which is open in the same computer ? May be using `CreateLink` ?

Comment: It's not fully clear what you are asking. What does it mean to "execute an expression to another Mathematica GUI Window"? What are you trying to achieve, in practical terms?

Comment: I have built a frontend for my simulation. Now I want Mathematica to compute and return me the output. Till this it works fine with WSTP. But now I want Mathematica generated 2D and 3D Plots. For this I can export Mathematica returned expressions as an image or 3ds graphics and render that in my application. But for that I need to write a good viewer, and I am too lazy for that. So I want a `Manipulate`, `Plot` or `Graphics3d` or `Wolfarm Alpha` command to be executed to another Mathematica window which is open in the same computer. Better if I can talk to that frontend via TCP socket

Comment: Sorry, I still do not follow. Also, if you merely have a simulation that needs to be accessible from Mathematica, I do not understand why you are not using an installable MathLink program (i.e. why you are not calling C from Mathematica rather than Mathematica from C)

Comment: Because I need some initial GUI controls to shape the inputs and I need some other GUI controls to work on intermediate data. It is easier to work with those GUI controls in C++.

Comment: Also `Manipulate` doesn't give enough flexibility of GUI controls, that I can achieve from an external C++ GUI (which is talking to Mathematica over WSTP)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused why you're even using Mathematica in this case. Given what you've told @Szabolcs, you seem to only want its 3D plotting abilities. It's probably easiest to just use a C++ 3D plotting library, since you seem to have all the other front-end stuff down. That said, I think this is an interesting question in general and would like to see an answer to it.

Comment: I am doing some analysis in frequency domain, solving some reccurence relations, and then doing some optimization based on that analysis. Output of that optimization is used to take certain actions on a set of resources (which I do in C++). Also as the input is in a complicated hierarchical shape I use C++ based GUI to shape that. I know I can do all computations in C/C++ or in any Turing compatible language. But I choose to do the computation part in Mathematica instead. But I need intermediate visuaizations for my references. I know that I can create a viewer, but I don't have enough time.

Comment: I understand what I am trying to do is kind of luxury, because there are other way out (which are not that good). Like creating a cdf which have all the visualizaions packed inside it. But this is my backup plan. And this is how I have solved the problem for now. But I would love to see if I can send some command to another Mathematica GUI frontend. If that works I would say that is my `visualisation` window, just like people use a debug window, or logging window.

Comment: I have no experience with such links but this answer seems to be something you could use: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138433/5478