# I would like to monitor a file sieve.txt and take its contents in dynamic

Tags: dynamic

I would like to monitor a file sieve.txt and take its contents in dynamic.
:I did this but Dynamic does not work in this case:

```
Dynamic[srv=Import[C:\\maths\\sieve.txt, "Data"]

Dynamic[srv]
```

Is there a function or a small program that can do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Does it help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138433/5478 ?

Comment: Try e.g.: Dynamic[Refresh[t = Get["d:/tmp/t.txt"], UpdateInterval -> 1]]

Answer (score 5):

This function will monitor the file modification timestamp to determine if the contents need to be imported again:

```
Clear[monitorFile]
monitorFile[
  Dynamic[contents_], 
  file_String?FileExistsQ,
  importFunction : _ : Import, 
  formatFun : _ : Identity
] := DynamicModule[{
   modificationDate,
   display = ""
   },
  DynamicWrapper[
   DynamicWrapper[
    Column[{
      Dynamic[modificationDate, TrackedSymbols :> {modificationDate}],
      Dynamic[display, TrackedSymbols :> {display}]
    }, Alignment -> Left]
    ,
    modificationDate;(* This triggers the update *)
    If[ DateObjectQ[modificationDate],
        contents = importFunction[file];
        display = formatFun[contents]
        ,
        contents = display = Missing[]
    ],
    SynchronousUpdating -> False,
    TrackedSymbols :> {modificationDate}
   ]
   ,
   modificationDate = Quiet @ Information[File[file], "LastModificationDate"],
   SynchronousUpdating -> True,
   UpdateInterval -> 1.
 ]
]
```

Example usage:

```
file = "table.txt";
Export[file, List /@ Range[5], "Table"];
monitorFile[Dynamic[x], file, Import[#, "Table"] &, Grid]
```

Note that I'm not 100% sure that `Information[File[file], "LastModificationDate"]` works on all operating systems since there are a number of different timestamps associated with files depending on the OS. You may have to look at `Information[File[file], "Properties"]` to see what property you need to query.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `Dynamic`s will only update when they need to be displayed, so you can't use this as a background file monitor. If that's what you need, you should look at `ScheduledTask` instead.

## Update

I made the function more robust in the situation where the file gets deleted suddenly.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dynamic[Refresh[Import["sieve.txt", "Data"], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

Comment: This tries to import file each second, could be problematic for larger files. File last modification date would be better but I don't remember how fast it is.

Comment: Perfect. I’ll test it.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks,  you, your solution is complete https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138433/5478 and suits me perfectly, because the file watcher will track the size of the file and when it changes automatically reload the contents.